# inner join with COUNT() and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, join

I am using phpMyAdmin to test this query but keep getting a syntax error. I've tried looking it up in the MySql manual and trying other syntactical possibilities but I've gotten older in this process. Thanks for your help

SELECT image_title, image_id, COUNT(other_sales.*) FROM art
INNER JOIN other_sales ON (art.image_id=other_sales.image_id)
GROUP BY (other_sales.image_id);

MySQL said: Documentation

## Documentation

## 1052 - Column 'image_id' in field list is ambiguous

Ultimately, I want to count the number of times a specific number (image_id) occurs in the 'other_sales' table

Comment: replace count(other_sales.*) with count(*)

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot these 1064 errors:

The error message gives a snippet of your query. The first character of the snippet is the first character the MySQL interpreter could not understand.

So in the case of your query, it's

```
SELECT image_title, image_id, COUNT(other_sales.*) FROM art INNER JOIN ...
ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

where `g` means good and `b` means bad.

Your actual problem:  you can't put more than one value in a `COUNT()` function. You tried to put `COUNT(something.*)` which makes no sense to count.

Notice that `COUNT(*)` is a special case meaning just count the rows.

Answer (score 1):

the tables `art` and `other sales` probably both have the column `image_id`.
specify the table before the column like `art.imageid` or asign a alias to the table and then to the column like so

```
SELECT o.image_title, o.image_id, COUNT(*)
FROM art a JOIN other_sales o ON (art.id=other_sales.image_id) 
GROUP BY (o.image_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see that now. There are 2 problems with my original code.

1. I should have chosen the specific column name instead of using *
2. image_id is a column name that appears in both tables I am accessing. That will cause an "ambiguous" error.

Below is the original code and the corrected code:

original:
SELECT image_title, image_id, COUNT(other_sales.*) FROM art INNER JOIN other_sales ON (art.image_id=other_sales.image_id) GROUP BY (other_sales.image_id);

corrected:
SELECT image_title, art.image_id, COUNT(other_sales.image_id) FROM art INNER JOIN other_sales ON (art.image_id=other_sales.image_id) GROUP BY (other_sales.image_id);

thanks for the help